# code command using ssh-remote pluguin using bash

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, ssh

Is there a way to open the visual studio code using "code" command on linux terminal but opening it with a specific ssh folder.

On documentation i have read that you can open an specific path with code command but what i want to know if this is also possible with an ssh folder using the ssh-Remote plugin.

> > > code /path/

Visual studio code also stores your ssh folders on recent folders so i wish that there's a command to call that path or something like that.

Comment: You can only setup another connection for it. Because if you run code on the remote instance (assuming the remote instance has a gui and has vscode installed), it's gonna open vscode from there which isn't what you want.